# SDMA Freescale imx535

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded, arm

This question deals with running the SDMA engine on Freescale i.mx devices ([i.MX535](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=i.MX535&nodeId=018rH3ZrDR988D) to be specific)?

I'd like to receive packets greater than 32 bytes from a UART and fetch them automatically with the SDMA engine. Is this possible? Does anyone have additional information about SDMA use?

**Edit:** I will be a little bit more specific about my situation and issues.

I have managed to load and run my own SDMA script. The Test bench is,

1. Setup a UART communication (9600 , raw) on UART2 (not using the standard Freescale UART driver).
2. Setup UART2 rx dma request with threshold level 16.
3. Setup SDMA Channel for UART2 which run a script like *UART 2 external memory*.

This setup works well with packets less than 32 bytes but if the size is greater than 32 bytes data is dropped with an `RX FIFO Overrun` bit set. The same error occurs if we use the standard Freescale UART driver with SDMA enabled on UART2 (prints out Status Regs from UART with *DMA ERROR* label).

**Q1.** Did someone manage to receive packets greater then 32 Byte on *normal* UARTs like UART2.  Implying there is a BUG in my script.

How do *normal* UARTs indicate they are also shared UARTs which are connect directly to the SDMA core. I have tested this UART script on UART3 too. My conclusion and observation are:
First I test it with the standard Freescale UART driver and SDMA enabled using standard scripts. This works fine with Packets greater then 32 bytes and a baud rate of 1MHZ. So i hoped to get this working with my own script and UART driver but i can't build a script which reads from UART3 RX register.

**Q2.** Has somebody written a script that reads data from a shared UART?

Answer (score 2):

You must sell your first born to **Freescale** to get this kind of information.  They have *many* internal documents.  It is not an easy task to get answers.

Try and fetch this repo: git://git.pengutronix.de/git/imx/sdma-firmware.git

There are various routines in ROM with an API that you need to understand.  Generally there isn't enough RAM to put all your code there, if you wish to modify things.  Maybe you can use Sasha's disassembler and try to tweak one of your binaries.

The **IMX25 reference** has a lot more *public* documentation on the SDMA controller; I can see very little on SDMA in the **IMX53 reference manual**.

Comment: thanks for the response,the repo i already know and i ask some questions to the freescale support too but until now i get no solution for my Problem. i edit my Question to be more specific, perhaps you can help too

Comment: If you have this type of information, did you have to sign any **NDA** agreements?  It is hard for people to give you information.

Answer (score 2):

> Has somebody written a script that reads data from a shared UART?

If you want to read/write data from shared Peripherals you have to access data via the memory mapped "peripheral x memory space" areas in internal SDMA ram (0x1000-0xFFFF). So in my case, access to 0x3000 internal sdma ram reads data from UART3 RXD Register.